# Using grep to check if a variable stored in a file is not undefined or blank

Tags: regex, linux, shell, grep, environment-variables

Consider a file called `.env` containing:

```
env1=foo
env2=bar
```

I use grep with a regular expression to confirm there's a line defining `env2` with a non-blank value, expecting to get a match.

```
~$ grep -c -i '^env2=(?!\s*$).+' .env
0
```

Returns 0 matches... but why? I got a match when I tested the same thing here: https://regexr.com/6g7of

Sanity check:

```
~$ grep -c -i '^env2=bar' .env
1
```

To confirm multiline is supported in case I had a doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `^env2=(?!\s*$).+` regex is a PCRE compliant regex, but you are using `grep` with the default POSIX BRE regex engine.

If you use a GNU grep, you can use the `-P` option to make `grep` treat the pattern as a PCRE regex:

```sh
grep -cPi '^env2=(?!\s*$).+' .env
```

Else, use a POSIX compliant pattern,`

```sh
grep -c -i '^env2=.*[^[:space:]]' .env
```

Here, the regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `env2=` - literal text
- `.*` - zero or more chars
- `[^[:space:]]` - a non-whitespace char.